# CALayer frame gives strange position

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am currently trying to use **CALayer** to show a mask and then use this mask to crop the picture according to this mask but I can't find a way to get the good position and size of my mask in my image.

When I draw my mask, I use **kCAGravityResizeAspectFill** to keep the ratio of my image. In this case the layer use the height to fill my screen height and compute the proper width / (x, y) to keep the ratio.

```
CGRect screenViewRect = [self.viewForBaselineLayout bounds];

CGFloat screenViewWidth = screenViewRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenViewHeight = screenViewRect.size.height;

masqueLayer.frame = CGRectMake(screenViewWidth *0.45, screenViewHeight*0.05, screenViewWidth *0.10, screenViewHeight*0.92);
masqueLayer.contents = (__bridge id)([UIImage imageNamed:masqueJustif].CGImage);
masqueLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
[self.layer insertSublayer:masqueLayer atIndex:2];
```

As I get the mask on my screen I can easily see that the **screenViewWidth *0.10** is not respected as I wanted, but my trouble come from the fact that when I get the frame or my layer the width isn't updated and so I can't get the real position of my layer on my screen.

Is there a method to get the **real** position of my layer on my screen.

I am actually trying to get the crop rectangle with this (considering my ratio is 21/29.7 as it is a A4 mask). This code is actually working on IPad but not on Iphone as the ratio is different :

```
CGRect outputRect = [masqueLayer convertRect:masqueLayer.bounds toLayer:self.layer];
outputRect.origin.y *= 2;
outputRect.size.height *= 2;
outputRect.size.width = outputRect.size.height * (21/29.7);
```

I also tried using my mask percentage :

```
    CGRect outputRect = masqueLayer.frame;
    outputRect.origin.y = its.size.height * 0.05;
    outputRect.origin.x = its.size.width * 0.45 * masqueLayer.anchorPoint.x;
    outputRect.size.height = its.size.height * 0.92;
    outputRect.size.width = its.size.height * 0.92 * (21/29.7);
```

Here is a screenshot of my mask on another layer. I want to extract the image bounded by the blue corner (which is the border of my layer)
[image: Screen]

Thanks.

Comment: can u show the screenshot of what you want to achive?

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: so u want the image covered in the blue cornered rectangle frame ?

Comment: yes that's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: then y dont u screenshot the layer behind the blue corner layer with the blue cornered layer size ?

Comment: As I said in my question, this is my problem, the frame of my layer has some strange values which seems not updated considering what I have on my screen (like the width of my calayer frame is about 40pt and my height : 414 pt with isn't the ratio I have on both my screen and picture I am using (which is 21/29.7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95316/discussion-between-clad-clad-and-mr-t).